# Eigen error: please_protect_your_min_with_parentheses

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, eigen, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to test Eigen's NonLinear Optimization capabilities by running the testcode that comes with the package.

I'm stuck (more like baffled) with these errors :

```
Error   5   error C2039: 'please_protect_your_min_with_parentheses' : is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<double>'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\eigen-eigen-5097c01bcdc4\unsupported\eigen\src\nonlinearoptimization\lmpar.h    184
Error   7   error C2039: 'please_protect_your_min_with_parentheses' : is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<double>'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\eigen-eigen-5097c01bcdc4\unsupported\eigen\src\nonlinearoptimization\lmpar.h    28
Error   6   error C2065: 'please_protect_your_min_with_parentheses' : undeclared identifier c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\eigen-eigen-5097c01bcdc4\unsupported\eigen\src\nonlinearoptimization\lmpar.h    184
Error   8   error C2065: 'please_protect_your_min_with_parentheses' : undeclared identifier c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\eigen-eigen-5097c01bcdc4\unsupported\eigen\src\nonlinearoptimization\lmpar.h    28
```

by the way the line that (I think)causes this goes like this:

```
#define min(A,B) please_protect_your_min_with_parentheses
```

and the errors refer to this line (in 2 different places mentioned above as lines 28 and 184):

```
const Scalar dwarf = std::numeric_limits<Scalar>::min();
```

Any advice shall and will be much appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It requests you to change the line to this one:

```
const Scalar dwarf = (std::numeric_limits<Scalar>::min)();
```

So that if `min` function-like macro is defined, it will not be substituted.

The problem is that Microsoft Windows headers define the `min` macro, so standard C++ code that includes Windows headers may fail to compile. The solution that portable C++ libraries implement is wrapping their calls to the standard `min` functions with parentheses, as above. The test code that you compile seems to check that this technique is used by the code.

The problem of the above approach is that you will not be able to perform an unqualified call to `min(a,b)` with argument dependent lookup, since adding parentheses causes the name to be looked up independent of the arguments.

Another solution that one can apply to her own code is to define the NOMINMAX flag before including any Windows header or undefining the `min`/`max` macros. This is not usually done by library code since they are not supposed to tweak the configuration of the user code.

Comment: thanks finally i could build it, but for some reason eluding me tests abort at level 7 starting with  CALL_SUBTEST/*_7*/(testNistMGH17());
    then when i comment it out again with CALL_SUBTEST/*_8*/(testNistLanczos1()); and gave up trying the rest at this point